# How can I access the original names of my input fields, in dot notation, from formik context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I have a formik form with a shape that looks something like this:

```
values:{
    category1:{
        name
        },
    category2:{
        name
        }
    }
```

The names of the fields are `category1.name` and `category2.name`.

I'm trying to code up a validation errors handler that will accept the errors from formik context, and which can then provide a clickable link to whichever field is erroring out. My issue lies in the way that formik returns errors. They follow the same format as the final submitted object. Thus, my errors object looks something like this:

```
errors:{
    category1:{
        name: "error for category 1 name"
        },
    category2:{
        name: "error for category 2 name"
        }
    }
```

I can flatten the object to recursively determine the dot notation name of each error as something `category1.name` and `category2.name` with a helper function, but that's sloppy looking and gives anyone reviewing my code something else to view and consider.

Does formik expose the names of fields in dot notation anywhere? For reference, I am using the [useFormikContext](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext) hook, and I am passing the context generated from that (IE `myFormikContext = useFormikContext(myFormikOptions)`, and I'm searching for the original field names in `myFormikContext`)

Tech stack is typescript with formik for form generation and yup for validation, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Does appending `'as const'` to your objects, help?

```js
values:{
  category1:{
    name
  },
  category2:{
    name
  }
} as const;
```

Comment: I think my original question may be unclear. When I'm generating the component, I give it a name of `category1.name`, a string. I can't declare it as a const because it's one of several options fed into formik.